# Dependencies in a custom useAsyncEffect are overflowing, how to make it run once and whenever the deps update?

Tags: reactjs

So I created a useAsyncHook for querying a regular API, however, I notice I have a dependency issue since the browser will overflow if the dependencies are empty arrays.

I tried several things like state managing differently these dependencies, I created a simple sandbox to showcase a simple example.

This is how I consume it.

```
import useAsyncEffect from "./useAsyncEffect";

const useSomethingExample = ({ processes, datasets }) => {
  console.log(processes);
  console.log(datasets);

  return useAsyncEffect(async () => {
    await new Promise((resolve) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        resolve({ processes, datasets });
      }, 300);
    });
  }, [processes, datasets]);
};

export default useSomethingExample;
```

You'll have to change lines 6 and 7 in App.tsx to empty arrays instead of null to see the issue.

[sanbox example]https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typescript-forked-gd510i?file=/src/useAsyncEffect.ts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dependencies in the [depsArray] are compared by reference for non-primitive objects (string, number, boolean). And in javascript `[] ===[]` => false. So on each rerender of your component with this hook the new empty arrays are created and passed to the hook, and due to they have a different references every time - useEffect is triggered, updating data, causing the rerender of the calling component end etc.

You can use state variables for those arrays in the first place.

```
export default function App() {
  const [processes, setProcesses] = useState([]);
  const [datasets, setDatasets] = useState([]);

  const { result } = useSomethingExample({
    processes: processes,
    datasets: datasets
  });

  console.log("result");
  console.log(result);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      useAsyncEffect fails if processes are [] or datasets are []
    </div>
  );
}
```

If you really want it to look nicer - you can modify your `useSomethingExample` a bit by adding an internal state. The `useEffect`s in it are executing `functional state updates` using lodash `isEqual` method, so if arrays are equal - old array (curr) is returned, old reference, so the main `useEffect` is not re-executed. You can use your comparison implementation, lodash is not mandatory.

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import _ from "lodash";
import useAsyncEffect from "./useAsyncEffect";

const useSomethingExample = ({ processes, datasets }) => {
  const [p, setP] = useState(processes);
  const [d, setD] = useState(datasets);

  useEffect(() => {
    setP((curr) => {
      if (_.isEqual(curr, processes)) return curr;
      return processes;
    });
  }, [processes]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setD((curr) => {
      if (_.isEqual(curr, datasets)) return curr;
      return datasets;
    });
  }, [datasets]);

  console.log(processes);
  console.log(datasets);

  return useAsyncEffect(async () => {
    await new Promise((resolve) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        resolve({ processes: p, datasets: d });
      }, 300);
    });
  }, [p, d]);
};

export default useSomethingExample;
```